# Can a ViewController presented modally use the NavigationController's toolbar

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm trying to present modally a UITableViewController from a view controller in my navigation controller hierarchy. The modal view should display a toolbar.

Can the navigation controller's managed toolbar be used in view controllers presented modally or should I implement my own toolbar for these?

- If I present the controller modally with `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:filterVC animated:YES];` no toolbar is displayed.
- If I pushed the controller with: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:filterVC animated:YES];` the toolbar is displayed.

Here is the method I run from the init method of my UITableViewController.

```
    -(void)configureToolBar {

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    //ToolbarItem Done
    UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                              target:self 
                                                                              action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

    //ToolbarItem Cancel
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
    //Flexible Space
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleItem, cancelItem, doneItem, flexibleItem, nil];

    [doneItem release];
    [cancelItem release];
    [flexibleItem  release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, because a modal view controller becomes a child to the view controller that displays it, and this view controller is a subview of the navigation controller (i.e. the modal view has no connection with the NavigationController's hierarchy). You can present a navigation controller as a modal view controller, though, so you can pass your custom navbar buttons to it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to embed your VC inside a new UINavigationController and set the toolbar items again or you just add a UIToolbar to the bottom of your VC.